# Opening an Excel file in C# using Process.Start

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I'm trying to open an excel file using a button click. And for some reason it's not working. I've tried several things. Any ideas why they are not working?

Method 1 I have tried. This opens the file manager but does not open the proper file. It is definitely using the proper path to the file and the file does exist

```
private string fileCopy;

public RepairResultsControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void Show(PSRepair.AnalysisResults analysis, string pathNameCopy)
{
    fileCopy = pathNameCopy;
    Show();
}

private void btnGoToFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", "/select,"+ fileCopy);
}
```

Method 2. This just didn't open anything not sure why

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\username\Documents\newTest.xlsx");
```

Comment: Are there any Excel processes lurking in the background?

Comment: My project is an excel addin therefore it is open in the background. Is this an issue?

Comment: Ah, don't know in that scenario. When I used to automate Excel, I'd end out with inactive processes that woudln't respond or open. But if this is an addin, don't you have access to the Excel object model to open the spreadsheet through that?

Comment: .. your first code example will open explorer with the file selected, as that's what `explorer.exe /select` does. However the second one _should_ open the spreadsheet in Excel.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't I can't think of what could be wrong

Comment: @stuartd the first one only opens file explorer it does not bring me to the file location. Any ideas why?

Comment: Seems to work for me here..

Comment: The value is the path file so `C:\Users\username\Documents\newTest.xlsx`

Comment: Maybe it's in use somewhere in my project or something but I assume it should still bring me to the file location?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally, `Process.Start(@"C:\Users\username\Documents\newTest.xlsx");` would open your document in Excel.

However, you say in a comment that you are doing this from an Excel add-in which runs in the background. The solution needs to take this into account (the code sample assumes that you have a VSTO add-in, otherwise you need to adjust accordingly):

```
// make the running Excel instance visible
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Visible = true;

// open the workbook using Excel interop
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
```

Comment: I'm trying to open the `xlsx` file directly, and getting this exception: _Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform._

Comment: This depends likely on the value of the `UseShellExecute` property. Make sure it is set to true.

Comment: I was talking about `Process.Start`.

Comment: Yes, pass in a `ProcessStartInfo` with that property set to true. If it still fails, you probably need to repair Office.

Comment: "This depends likely on the value of the UseShellExecute property. Make sure it is set to true." was the culprit for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

With .NET Core use:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo{FileName = @"C:\Users\username\Documents\newTest.xlsx", UseShellExecute = true});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try running as an admin
2. Check for exceptions, also the start method should return a bool, check to make sure it is true.
3. Make SURE your xlsx files are associated with Excel(easy check for this is at a command prompt, type in your filename and hit enter... if excel opens you are good)
4. Check your system error logs.