# Open Office applications inside windows form using C# or VB.net

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, winforms, ms-word

i am working on some secure project in .net framework. For which i am going to make win from application and to make sure about security after once executing my windows form application i will disable all the controls like Alt, Tab etc. User can not be able to open any other application before finishing our application, but some of the applications that our user needs to use during execution of out application i.e MS Word, Power point, paint, Microsoft mathematics etc. Now i want to give user the menu for allowed applications and when user opens some application e.g. MS Word. That should be open in running windows form in new tab or in new window frame. So far i have done some R&D on it but not find any example in which any office application running inside windows frame.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these links can help you

I cannot comment yet but I hope I was able to help

[MSDN - C# run exe from a form, and keep the exe within the boundaries](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/94a67da1-8143-4e37-86c0-4deab0d1ec93/c-run-exe-from-a-form-and-keep-the-exe-within-the-boundaries-of-that-original-form?forum=winforms)

(These two are linked within the MSDN thread)

[Docking Window inside another Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836176/docking-window-inside-another-window)

[run a foreign exe inside a windows form app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762379/run-a-foreign-exe-inside-a-windows-form-app)

Comment: Hi,
This works fine. Can you please guide me how can i open directly the spread sheet instead of start screen in case of excel and the same open the document in case of Ms Word.
Thanks,

Comment: I'm not really deep in that matter, but I found this link.
[Opening an Excel file in C# using Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40913603/opening-an-excel-file-in-c-sharp-using-process-start)
I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your assistance. it works perfectly fine except non consistent behavior of word, power point, excel that sometime it opens inside the frame and sometimes it opens outside the frame. Can any body assists that is this behavior can be controllable. Thanks,